# Recursive python function to make two arrays equal?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, recursion

I'm attempting to write python code to solve a transportation problem using the Least Cost method. I have a 2D numpy array that I am iterating through to find the minimum, perform calculations with that minimum, and then replace it with a 0 so that the loops stops when `values` matches `constantarray`, an array of the same shape containing only 0s. The `values` array contains distances from points in `supply` to points in `demand`. I'm currently using a while loop to do so, but the loop isn't running because values.all() != constantarray.all() evaluates to False.

I also need the process to repeat once the arrays have been edited to move onto the next lowest number in `values`.

```
constarray = np.zeros((len(supply),len(demand)) #create array of 0s
sandmoved = np.zeros((len(supply),len(demand)) #used to store information needed for later
totalcost = 0 
while values.all() != constantarray.all(): #iterate until `values` only contains 0s
    m = np.argmin(values,axis = 0)[0] #find coordinates of minimum value 
    n = np.argmin(values,axis = 1)[0]
    if supply[m] > abs(demand[m]): #all demand numbers are negative
        supply[m]+=demand[n] #subtract demand from supply
        totalcost +=abs(demand[n])*values[m,n] 
        sandmoved[m,n] = demand[n] #add amount of 'sand' moved to an empty array
        values[m,0:-1] = 0 #replace entire m row with 0s since demand has been filled
        demand[n]=0 #replace demand value with 0
    elif supply[m]< abs(demand[n]):
        demand[n]+=supply[m] #combine positive supply with negative demand
        sandmoved[m,n]=supply[m]
        totalcost +=supply[m]*values[m,n] 
        values[:-1,n]=0 #replace entire column with 0s since supply has been depleted
        supply[m] = 0
```

There is an additional if statement for when `supply[m]==demand[n]` but I feel that isn't necessary. I've already tried using nested for loops, and so many different syntax combinations for a while loop but I just can't get it to work the way I want it to. Even when running the code block over over by itself, m and n stay the same and the function removes one value from `values` but doesn't add it to `sandmoved`. Any ideas are greatly appreciated!!

Comment: We don't have any data to run your code, what are `values`, `supply`, `demand`? Please provide a working example that gives the wrong results and indicate what are the expected correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is an example from an old implementation of mine:

```
import numpy as np

values = np.array([[3, 1, 7, 4],
                   [2, 6, 5, 9],
                   [8, 3, 3, 2]])
demand = np.array([250, 350, 400, 200])
supply = np.array([300, 400, 500])

totCost = 0
MAX_VAL = 2 * np.max(values)  # choose MAX_VAL higher than all values
while np.any(values.ravel() < MAX_VAL):
    # find row and col indices of min
    m, n = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(values), values.shape)
    if supply[m] < demand[n]:
        totCost += supply[m] * values[m,n]
        demand[n] -= supply[m]
        values[m,:] = MAX_VAL   # set all row to MAX_VAL
    else:
        totCost += demand[n] * values[m,n]
        supply[m] -= demand[n]
        values[:,n] = MAX_VAL   # set all col to MAX_VAL
```

Solution:

```
print(totCost)
 # 2850
```

Basically, start by choosing a `MAX_VAL` higher than all given values and a `totCost = 0`. Then follow the standard steps of the algorithm. Find row and column indices of the smallest cell, say `m`, `n`. Select the m-th supply or the n-th demand whichever is smaller, then add what you selected multiplied by `values[m,n]` to the `totCost`, and set all entries of the selected row or column to `MAX_VAL` to avoid it in the next iterations. Update the greater value by subtracting the selected one and repeat until all values are equal to `MAX_VAL`.